# How to submit a form using jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm unable to submit a form using method post.

1. The first error that occured was a 405 but I was able to solved it using this [solution](http://www.somacon.com/p126.php).
2. Now occurs a 403 error, how can I solve it?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginForm').submit(function () {
        //some business logic...
        $.mobile.changePage($('#menuPage'));
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Login</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post" id="loginForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="utilizadorText">Inserir Utilizador</label>
                <input type="text" id="utilizadorText" name="utilizadorText" />
                <label for="palavraChaveText">Inserir Palavra Chave</label>
                <input type="password" id="palavraChaveText" name="palavraChaveText" />
                <input type="submit" id="loginAnchor" class="submit" value="Login" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>     

<div data-role="page" id="menuPage">
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Menu</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content">    
        Menu
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are trying to submit the form to the loginPage and than change the page to menuPage. This doesn't make sense to me. What actions are you trying to perform here? If you want to be able to take form data from the context of the loginPage and than apply business logic to it than the solution below might help.

[Possible Solution #1](http://jsfiddle.net/2aFNC/19/)